# JAVA I/O use GPIO I2C and SPI on different One chip systems

Tags: java, io, gpio, i2c, spi

at the moment I am working with a nvidia jetson tx1 and java and I become quit frustrated and confused.
I just managed to get used with sysfs gpio control. As a next step I try to control I2C / SPI via Java. But this does not seem to work over sysfs only with ioctl which can only be accessed with c.
So I started looking around to find some libs for java that might help me.
and I found:

- jdk.dio
- pi4j
- diozero

for jdk.dia I find very little action and forums communication I can't even find a download somewhere.. maybe it too old?

pi4j seems to be only made for the rpi and needs an other library that's only for pi.

diozere is not official from oracle and needs many other dependencies too.

Does someone of you maybe tried to use java with I2C / SPI on non rPI chips and can give me some information?